# How to handle image required field in case of update, react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react hook form to upload a file, and my file upload field is:

```
<input
    className={`form-control ${
        errors["cover_image"] ? "border-red-500" : ""
    }`}
    type="file"
    id="cover_image"
    {...register("cover_image")}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

and I have yup validation as:

```
cover_image: Yup.mixed()
    .test("name", "Cover Image is required", (value) => {
        return value[0] && value[0].name !== "";
    })
    .test("fileSize", "File must be less than 2MB", (value) => {
        return value[0] && value[0].size <= 2000000;
    })
    .test("type", "Only image are supported", (value) => {
        return value[0] && value[0].type.includes("image");
    }),
```

It is working fine in the case of creating a page, it shows required, when not uploaded, but in the case of the edit page, it is showing a field is required, if I don't upload any file. There is a file value on `item.cover_image`.

I have also tried `defaultValue={item.cover_image}`, but it is not allowing to set me default value in case of edit. How would be the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an external package to validate I would recommend using validation of `react-hook-form`

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm()

  console.log({ errors: formState.errors })

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
      <input
        type="file"
        {...register('cover_image', {
          validate: value => {
            const isExists = !!value.length
            const isGoodSize = value[0] && value[0].size <= 2000000
            const isImageType = value[0] && value[0].type.includes('image')

            if (!isExists) return "Cover Image is required"
            if (!isGoodSize) return 'File must be less than 2MB'
            if (!isImageType) return 'Only image are supported'

            return undefined
          }
        })}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: how could I control the value on isEdit, for example, if user remove old image this needs to be required on edit page as well.

Comment: I updated it, right now should work as a charm.

Comment: Finally, I think I understand your case. On editing, you should fill the form with the data and check like in the normal case.

Comment: But to help with that I will need more code / info how you are fetching the data to edit

Comment: cover_image is available on `item.cover_image`, on edit page `item.cover_image` will have value like: `dummy_image.jpg` and in case of create this field will be `null`

Comment: Ok, so your server will return the name of the file. Got it.

Comment: So if your server is returning string then you can not use input in this case. You will need to display the file name ( as a normal text ) and the button to remove the file. Uploading should be only available when the file was not uploaded.

Comment: I recommend separate uploading file logic to the separate component.